# Полноэкранный режим

Tags: awt, java

Как в AWT / Swing реализовать полноэкранный режим (`Full-Screen mode`)? Я нашел такое:

```
GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
gd.setFullScreenWindow(this);
```

Но это мне не подходит, потому что тогда я не могу показывать диалоги поверх этого развернутого окна. Как мне сделать такой же режим, но с диалогами? Как пример можете посмотреть работу браузера в полноэкранном режиме, там всё хорошо с диалогами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я люблю вот так

---

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```